# Additional condition for normal space to be metrizable

Tags: general-topology

Regular + second countable implies normal. But the Urysohn Metrization Theorem shows that regular + second countable also implies metrizable. And metrizable implies normal. But I wonder what is the additional condition for normal space to be metrizable. Thanks!

Comment: The existence of a $\sigma$-locally finite basis: see the Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The following are equivalent for a space $X$:

1. $X$ is metrisable.
2. $X$ is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base.
3. $X$ is $T_4$ and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base.

1 implies 3 is trivial (as soon as you know that all metric spaces have such a base, and are normal), 3 implies 2 is trivial as $T_4$ implies $T_3$ and 2 implies 1 is the harder part of the [Nagata-Smirnov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem).

So the additional condition is the same for $T_4$ and $T_3$.